# 64 Bit Java Path in Cygwin

Tags: java, path, cygwin

Ok, so this is actually quite a long story, but i'll try and keep it pretty short. So I'm trying to get the WebOS SDK working on Windows using Cygwin. Well, it wasn't working. It kept complaining that i was using a 32 bit version of java instead of 64 bit. the explenation for that problem is pretty easy to figure out. my PATH variable was set wrong and was pointing to my 32 bit installation of Java. Simple solution YOU'D THINK. apparantly not. for some reason, despite my best efforts, i cannot get the 64 bit version of java written into the PATH variable. The problem:
Cygwin doesn't like spaces in the Path variable, even though the path variable is littered with spaces, it won't accept it when i add my own space. After a lot of googling, i've found multiple accurances of this problem, and multiple solutions. but none of them seem to work. i always get exactly the same error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

The error is pretty self explanetary, basically its not reading anything past the first space, and i have no such directory as C:/Program so it spits out an error, my question is how do i get it to except a space, because changing the name of the directory is not an option, too many things depend on it. heres what i've tried so far:

```
$PATH=$PATH:C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6
$PATH=$PATH:"'pwd'" (while in java directory)
$PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin (hay, i had to try)
$PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/"Program Files"/Java/jre6/bin
$PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre6/bin (escape character was rumored to work
$PATH=$PATH:'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin'
$PATH=$PATH:"`/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin`"
```

and i think that was it, if anyone knows how to actually do it properly (or improperly but working for all i care) it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

--
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have the option of using the **cygpath** tool to help.  **Cygpath** can be used to convert from a Window's path to a Unix path, but that doesn't directly handle spaces, so you need to do a two step  process, first eliminate the spaces by converting to a DOS (short) path name, then convert to a Unix style path:

```
PATH=$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin")):${PATH}
PATH=$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP webOS\PDK\bin")):${PATH}
PATH=$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP webOS\SDK\bin")):${PATH}
PATH=$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP webOS\SDK\bin\novacom")):${PATH}
```

The end result will be something like (short names may differ slightly):

```
/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~3/HPWEBO~1/SDK/bin/novacom:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~3/HPWEBO~1/SDK/bin:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~3/HPWEBO~1/PDK/bin:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/Java/jre6/bin:....other path elements....
```

One thing to keep in mind when using this, **cygpath** generates an error if the provided path actually does not exist because it can not create the short path for a non-existent path.

What is nice about this approach is that if you set Windows environment variables (like for example JAVA_HOME) then you can use that environment variable in the convert operation inside the .bash_profile, since all Windows environment variables are visible when the profile is being  loaded.  So if you had in the Windows environment

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre
```

then the cygpath command can be

```
$(cygpath -u $(cygpath -m -s "${JAVA_HOME}\bin"))
```

which means you only ever need to update via the Windows settings if the java install changes.

Answer (score 2):

In .bash_profile:

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre6/bin/:${PATH}
PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/HP\ webOS/PDK/bin
PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/HP\ webOS/SDK/bin
PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/HP\ webOS/SDK/bin/novacom
```

Adds the paths to your .bash_profile and both java and the webOS SDK tools should be available.